# XSL value-of select="" showing an empty square in table

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<supermarket>
  <store-name>Sunshine Farmer&#39;s Market</store-name>
  <aisle>
    <number>1</number>
    <tag>Dry Goods</tag>
    <item>
      <item-name>Flour</item-name>
      <price>$3.99</price>
      <sale>No</sale>
      <brand>Full Moon Mills</brand>
    </item>
  </aisle>
</supermarket>
```

That's the XML.
Here's the table I'm having trouble with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Sunshine Farmer&#39;s Market</h2>
    <table border="3">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>On Sale</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="supermarket/aisle/item">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="item-name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="sale"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="brand"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I just tweaked some things from the original example, and the original worked fine, but for some reason this just shows emptiness in the 2nd row of the table. Could someone explain why this doesn't work, and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post source code as code samples, minimal but complete to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="price/>` is a syntax error, the attribute value lacks the double quote to terminate/delimit it.

Comment: Still having issues.

Comment: You need to post a minimal but complete XSLT to allow us to reproduce the "issues". A snippet without any context doesn't allow us to tell where you failed or your processsor or development environment fails.

Comment: Trying to feed your "input" sample to an XML parser I get a clear error message "Error parsing XML input at 14:3 : The 'store-name' start tag on line 3 position 4 does not match the end tag of 'supermarket'. Line 14, position 3.". So start with some editor that supports you in creating a well-formed XML input before throwing it at an XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Apparently <store-name> had no ending tag. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: So does that fail with any XSLT processor to output the two `tr` elements with `td` elements containing data? Or only at w3schools? I remember they had issues with feeding content with character reference from HTML to Javascript to the XML parser and XSLT processor. The XML seems finally fixed and the current XSLT is fine to produce a table with data, for instance at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakAU.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're asking. I just got started learning XML

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using the code you posted (after 5 edits).

Comment: Well yes, I've already fixed the problem thanks to @MartinHonnen so I changed it

Comment: If you have fixed the problem, then please delete the question.

Comment: why would I do that?

Comment: What is the current state of your question, does the code that you have now (both XML and XSLT) give you the desired result (e.g. a HTML document with table containing the data from the XML) or do you still get "an empty square"?

Comment: Yes, in case it was not clear, the problem has been fixed.